# shadow in bold characters when using stix package

Tags: bold, boldmath, stix

I'm trying to typeset the symbols within a pseudo-code using the stix package. I tried with `\boldsymbol` but this didn't get the characters bold. I managed to get the characters in bold using the bm package but there's a strange shadow showing (see figure below).
This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{stix}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{LS1}{stix}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"1F}

\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\bs}[1] {\bm{#1}}

%\newcommand{\bs}[1] {\boldsymbol{#1}}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \Function{getLocalArrays}{$w$}
      \State{$\left\{ \bs k, \bs f , \Omega \right\} \gets \bs \chi$}    
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly how `bm` works. Look closely, it is not a shadow, it is the character typeset several times spaced a tiny bit. This is what `bm` does when it cannot find a suitable bold.

Comment: You'll need to tell it where you get bold letters from. Why are you even mixing manually in the first place.

Comment: I have to match the fonts of a template, so I have written only a MWE above. The full document has more manual definitions. This example shows what I need: the 'w' character and the slanted `chi` character, but then bold symbols are wrong.

Comment: that is what I'm saying, you have specified where the letters should come from, but said nothing about the bold letters, thus, `bm` gives up and emulates. I tend to stay away from font mixes, since it is hard to understand what is going on and it is not super well documented. Have a look in `stix.sty` you'll notice there is something there about bold letters, you probably need something similar.

Comment: You were right! Adding `\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {bold}{LS1}{stix}     {b}{it}` fixed the normal characters! Still the 'chi' is double though.

Comment: Since we know it works with `stix` alone, it is the same issue (probably)

Comment: Adding `\SetSymbolFont{greeksymbols}     {bold}{LS1}{stix}     {b}{it}` will remove the shadow from the `\chi`, which is to say, it prevents the `\chi` from being made bold.

Answer (score 1):

The main problems are

1. the `ztmcm` font has no bold variant
2. you're not declaring a bold version for the `greekletters` symbol font

Redeclaring the `letters` symbol font just because you don't like the ‘w’ seems the wrong choice: do the converse, instead.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{stix}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\bs}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\DeclareSymbolFont{otherletters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{otherletters}{`w}

\usepackage{bm}


\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \Function{getLocalArrays}{$w$}
      \State{$\{ \bs{k}, \bs{f}, \Omega \} \gets \bs{\chi}+\chi$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see from the image, the first chi is bold.

Comment: I can't, the 'w' symbol that you see is needed in the document so I can't change it.

Comment: @aaragon Oh, sorry, wrong image!

Comment: This is so far the best solution, but the 'w' symbol is not the only one. Is there a shortcut to do the same for all a-zA-Z characters? I tried for example `\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{otherletters}{`N}` but these get the shadow now. And even the bold lowercase get the shadow too.

Comment: @aaragon There is no bold font for `ztmcm`. You may be luckier with NewTX fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Since I know you wanted the `w` style from `mathptmx` (or similar), I guessed that `newtxmath` would support bold letters better than the older `mathptmx`.  So I made searched `newtxmath.sty` for the letters and bold invocations.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{stix}
%\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}% mathptmx
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}% newtxmath
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}% newtxmath

\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{LS1}{stix}{m}{it}% stix
\SetSymbolFont{greeksymbols}     {bold}{LS1}{stix}     {b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"1F}

\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\bs}[1] {\bm{#1}}

%\newcommand{\bs}[1] {\boldsymbol{#1}}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \Function{getLocalArrays}{$w$}
      \State{$\left\{ \bs k , \bs f , \Omega \right\} \gets \bs \chi + \bs w$}    
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `unicode-math` to avoid all the font problems.
[image]

Compile with `Xe` or `Lua`Latex.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
%\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}% mathptmx
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}% newtxmath
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}% newtxmath


\newcommand{\bs}[1] {\ensuremath{\symbf{#1}}}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \Function{getLocalArrays}{$w$}
      \State{$\left\{ \bs k , \bs f , \Omega \right\} \gets \symbf{\chi}+\chi+\symbfup{\chi} + \bs w$}    
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As in the previous answer, the 'w' has to remain the same as in my post.

Comment: @aaragon Yo can combine it with suggestion by egreg.